# $f_1(x,y)=...=f_m(x,y)=0$ define finite algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

I was trying to solve this problem:

[image]

In a previous exercise I had proven that if two polynomials $f,g\in A[x,y]$ are coprime then the algebraic variety $V(f,g)$ is finite. Using this, what I did in my first attempt to solve the problem was to say: since the gcd of $f_1,...,f_m$ is a constant, some $f_i$ and $f_j$ must be coprime and then $V(f_1,...,f_m)\subset V(f_i,f_j)$ is finite. However I have realised that this is wrong because it may happen that there is no common factor for $f_1,...,f_m$, but still there is a common factor for each pair $f_i,f_j$.

What would be the correct way to approach this problem? Thanks for your help.

**Note:** I am not sure if this is important, but we may assume $A$ is a field.

Comment: If the set of common zeros is not finite, then it has an irreducible component of dimension 1, and then the irreducible equation of this component divides all $f_i$. At least it works for algebraically closed fields.